# Уважаемые эксперты, не понимаю, правильно ли в данном случае стоит двойной союз (не только, но и)

Tags: синтаксис

Антропология – это наука о происхождении и эволюции человека, которая изучает как его биологическую природу, так и социальную.

Comment: В предложении же союз "как, так и". Но можно заменить и на "не только, но и".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, всё тут у вас безупречно. :)

Comment: Извините, я просто иногда туплю сильно